# Creating boxplots in Pandas with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boxplot

```html
time xco2 lon lat mask front flag alt type
time         
2016-07-18 18:00:40 64835.00 400.345876 -77.665768 40.444690 1.00 2.0 0.00 3198.345000 warm
2016-07-18 18:00:50 64845.00 400.694926 -77.679259 40.450737 0.98 2.0 0.00 3199.400000 warm
2016-07-18 18:01:00 64855.00 401.107295 -77.692715 40.456796 0.98 2.0 0.00 3197.810000 warm
2016-07-18 18:01:10 64865.00 401.566160 -77.706165 40.462843 0.95 2.0 0.00 3196.500000 warm
2016-07-18 18:01:20 64875.00 401.752364 -77.719628 40.468837 1.00 2.0 0.00 3197.945000 warm
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2016-07-18 18:50:30 67825.00 391.580408 -80.799363 41.847582 0.81 NaN 0.00 3158.575000 cold
2016-07-18 18:50:40 67835.00 392.728223 -80.809320 41.851846 1.00 NaN 0.00 3241.930000 cold
2016-07-18 18:50:50 67845.00 392.051042 -80.819123 41.855974 0.43 NaN 1.14 3340.510000 cold
2016-07-18 18:51:00 67855.00 392.827331 -80.828735 41.860006 1.00 NaN 0.00 3428.665000 cold
2016-07-18 18:51:10 67862.95 392.934952 -80.836415 41.863085 1.00 NaN 0.00 3483.171186 cold
304 rows × 9 columns
```

I have many days to do and the current way I am doing it is very time consuming and I need a more efficient way! I need the data separated by either cold or warm, which I have a column that denotes that. Then I need each box and whisker to be 0.5 degree of lat. I am currently creating a new column manually for each half degree of data.The image is how I have been doing it, along with a snap shot of how the data is set up. [image: This is the old way of doing it and many of the days require much more columns]

```html
warm=np.arange(41.367440,44.13,0.25)
cold=np.arange(44.141705,46.321997,0.25)
print(warm)
print(cold)

xco2_0=df_layer102['XCO2'].loc()[(df_layer102['lat'] > warm[0]) & (df_layer102['lat'] <= warm[1])]
xco2_1=df_layer102['XCO2'].loc()[(df_layer102['lat'] > warm[1]) & (df_layer102['lat'] <= warm[2])]
xco2_2=df_layer102['XCO2'].loc()[(df_layer102['lat'] > warm[2]) & (df_layer102['lat'] <= warm[3])]
xco2_3=df_layer102['XCO2'].loc()[(df_layer102['lat'] > warm[3]) & (df_layer102['lat'] <= warm[4])]
xco2_4=df_layer102['XCO2'].loc()[(df_layer102['lat'] > warm[4]) & (df_layer102['lat'] <= warm[5])]
xco2_5=df_layer102['XCO2'].loc()[(df_layer102['lat'] > warm[5]) & (df_layer102['lat'] <= warm[6])]
xco2_6=df_layer102['XCO2'].loc()[(df_layer102['lat'] > warm[6]) & (df_layer102['lat'] <= warm[7])]
xco2_7=df_layer102['XCO2'].loc()[(df_layer102['lat'] > warm[7]) & (df_layer102['lat'] <= warm[8])]
xco2_8=df_layer102['XCO2'].loc()[(df_layer102['lat'] > warm[8]) & (df_layer102['lat'] <= warm[9])]
xco2_9=df_layer102['XCO2'].loc()[(df_layer102['lat'] > warm[9]) & (df_layer102['lat'] <= warm[10])]
xco2_10=df_layer102['XCO2'].loc()[(df_layer102['lat'] > warm[10]) & (df_layer102['lat'] <= warm[11])]
# xco2_11=df_layer10['XCO2'].loc()[(df_layer10['lat'] > warm[11]) & (df_layer10['lat'] <= warm[12])]
# xco2_12=df_layer10['XCO2'].loc()[(df_layer10['lat'] > warm[12]) & (df_layer10['lat'] <= warm[13])]

# xco2_11=df_layer10['XCO2'].loc()[(df_layer10['lat'] > warm[11]) & (df_layer10['lat'] <= cold[0])]
xco2_11=df_layer102['XCO2'].loc()[(df_layer102['lat'] >= cold[0]) & (df_layer102['lat'] <= cold[1])]
xco2_12=df_layer102['XCO2'].loc()[(df_layer102['lat'] > cold[1]) & (df_layer102['lat'] <= cold[2])]
xco2_13=df_layer102['XCO2'].loc()[(df_layer102['lat'] > cold[2]) & (df_layer102['lat'] <= cold[3])]
xco2_14=df_layer102['XCO2'].loc()[(df_layer102['lat'] > cold[3]) & (df_layer102['lat'] <= cold[4])]
xco2_15=df_layer102['XCO2'].loc()[(df_layer102['lat'] > cold[4]) & (df_layer102['lat'] <= cold[5])]
xco2_16=df_layer102['XCO2'].loc()[(df_layer102['lat'] > cold[5]) & (df_layer102['lat'] <= cold[6])]
xco2_17=df_layer102['XCO2'].loc()[(df_layer102['lat'] > cold[6]) & (df_layer102['lat'] <= cold[7])]
xco2_18=df_layer102['XCO2'].loc()[(df_layer102['lat'] > cold[7]) & (df_layer102['lat'] <= cold[8])]
# xco2_19=df_layer10['XCO2'].loc()[(df_layer1['lat'] > cold[8]) & (df_layer10['lat'] <= cold[9])]
# xco2_19=df_avg_up05['xco2_up'].loc()[(df_avg_up05['lat_up'] >  num1[5]) & (df_avg_up05['lat_up'] <= num1[6])]

# data_group_mid={'35 \u00b0':xco2_35_36, '36 \u00b0':xco2_36_37, '37 \u00b0':xco2_37_38, '38 \u00b0':xco2_38_39,  '39 \u00b0':xco2_39_40, '40 \u00b0':xco2_40_41, '41 \u00b0':xco2_41_42}
data_group_front={'46.14\u00b0':xco2_18, '45.89\u00b0':xco2_17, '45.64\u00b0':xco2_16, '45.39\u00b0':xco2_15,'45.14\u00b0':xco2_14,'44.89\u00b0':xco2_13,'44.69\u00b0':xco2_12,'44.39\u00b0':xco2_11,'44.11\u00b0':xco2_10,'43.86\u00b0':xco2_9, \
                 '43.61\u00b0':xco2_8,'43.36\u00b0':xco2_7,'43.11\u00b0':xco2_6,'42.86\u00b0':xco2_5,'42.61\u00b0':xco2_4,'42.36\u00b0':xco2_3,'42.11\u00b0':xco2_2,'41.86\u00b0':xco2_1,'41.61\u00b0':xco2_0}
df_xco2_front=pd.DataFrame(data=data_group_front)
df_xco2_front.count()
```

Comment: Okay! I just added the current way I am doing it

Comment: you can give seaborn a try, see if that fits your need: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html

Comment: I tried that too. I'm fairly new so I just wasnt sure if there is a faster way to create a new dataframe with these conditions or a another way to do it in the actual boxplot code.

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1:

What you can do is to create a new column that buckets 'lat' with pd.cut

```
df_layer102['lat_bucketed'] = pd.cut(df_layer102['lat'], numpy.append(warm, cold))
```

Here warm and cold are combined since they are non-overlapping and there is already a column indicating `cold` and `warm`. But you can bucket by each one individually.

---

### Method 2:

This can also be done manually with

```
df_layer102['lat_bucketed'] = ((df_layer102['lat'] - df_layer102['lat'].min())/0.5).astype(int)
```

This would give you a column with bucket index (e.g. 0, 1, 2, etc.).

---

Then, using seaborn, you can do

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
ax = sns.boxplot(x="lat_bucketed", y="XCO2", data=df_layer102)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! You are a lifesaver!